# SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a backup of an SQL Server DB in .bak format which I've successfully managed to restore to a local instance of SQL Server Express. I now want to export both the structure and data in a format that MySQL will accept. The tools that I use for MySQL management typically allow me to import/export .sql files, but unfortunately Microsoft didn't see fit to make my life this easy!

I can't believe I'm the first to run into this, but Google hasn't been a great deal of help. Has anybody managed this before?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129/how-to-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-mysql) thread.

Answer (score 1):

There will be 2 issues:
1) Datatypes.  There isn't always a direct analog between an MS SQL type and a MySQL type.  For example, MySQL handles timestamps very differently and has the cut-off for when you need to switch between varchar(n) and varchar(max)/text at a different value of n.  There are also some small differences in the numeric types.

2) Query syntax.  There are a few differences in the query syntax that, again, don't always have a 1:1 analog replacement.  The one that comes to the top of my mind is SELECT TOP N * FROM T in MS SQL becomes SELECT * FROM T LIMIT N in MySQL (MySQL makes paging loads easier).