# SQL Server Dump to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have the dump of ms sql server. Is it possible to use this dump to import data into my mysql db ?

What are the tools required to do the same ?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176728/ and others

Answer (score 3):

A little googling yielded [this](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-22_11-6060626.html) article on migrating a SQL Server database to MySQL 5.  I would hope there is a simpler solution, but if not, this should work.

In the interest of teaching to fish, the Google query that gave me the best results was:

`"data from sql-server to mysql"`

Comment: +1 for finding the best keyword.. I do believe that ppl should do a simple google search before asking a question..

Comment: @Scrum I agree about doing a google search but i prefer to post questions on stackoverflow as the answers are more reliable and come from people with experience

Comment: @anand Fair enough, In the future please specify what have you tried so far. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @Scrum thanks will keep that in mind when I ask questions from now on

Comment: @Kyle link to the article is dead.