# Move data from SQL Server/PostgreSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

There is a scenario, I have a SQL Server with tones of data in it. I need to copy certain fields from certain tables (hardly ever the whole table) to another server which runs MySQL.
Also there is another server with PostgreSQL. I need to do the same thing with it. 
Is there any know way to accomplish that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: One-time job or recurring sync?

Comment: Maybe this other post might help you:

[How to export data from SQL Server 2005 to MySQL][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129/how-to-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-mysql


Best Ragards

Comment: Eugen, its a recurring sync. Every hour. BizApps, Thanks!

Comment: BizApps, I believe that post is for moving the whole database, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember how flexible was the sql server exporting service, but it sounds you need a custom script to do it.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking about but was still wondering if there is any kind of solution...