# SqlServerToMySql : Transfer table from SqlServer to MySql Database

Tags: mysql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to export data from SQL Server 2005 to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129/how-to-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-mysql)

In my project, I want to transfer

> sql-server table to mysql table.

But I am not getting SQL command from SQL Server to run script on MySQL table.

Comment: SQL server means Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this tutorial: `Migrating a SQL Server database to MySQL 5.0` which explains the usage of [MySQL Migration Toolkit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/migration-toolkit/en/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Data Import](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) tool (ODBC import format) in dbForge Studio for MySQL.