# Can we convert SQL Server database file to SQLite file or .db file?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, sqlite

I have a SQL Server database and I want to generate a SQLite or .db file using ASP.NET Code is it possible to generate .db or SQLite file from SQL Server Database programatically?

I am using ASP.Net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26932/Convert-SQL-Server-DB-to-SQLite-DB), works pretty good

Comment: thanks for reply. Can you please suggest any other converter for My Sql database too ?

Comment: there are some suggestions which might help you here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129/how-to-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-mysql

Comment: hii Above Link is not working i m Unable to connect sql Sever Database

Comment: Here's a fork on GitHub that has seen more recent development: https://github.com/jschultz/sqlconverter