# Converting sql server database to mysql, needing change table structure and column names?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I need to achieve:

1. similar demands in this question: [How to export data from SQL Server 2005 to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129/how-to-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-mysql?rq=1)
2. change table structure and column names, for example:

Source(sql server):

Table A

```
id studentName
--------------    
1  John    
2  Jim
```

Table B

```
id teacherName
--------------
1  Kate
2  Mat
```

Destinations(mysql):

Table C    // Table A、B are combined

```
id name    // here the column name changed
-------
1  John
2  Jim
3  Kate
4  Mat
```

Comment: @sashkello UNION? Sorry, I am a rookie for this, could you give some more details? Thanks.

Comment: If you change structure and data it can hardly be called "conversion"...

Comment: What about your `id`s? You can't merge these as in your example, they will be duplicated. You can regenerate these but then any related tables with a foreign key will be pointing to the wrong record.