# Easiest method to export MS SQL SERVER database to MySql Database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a .Net console application that extracts data from webapi and fill 5 tables on a MS SQL Server database.

Now I have to export these tables to a MySql Database.
How can I do that in an easy way?

The Console Application is coded with Visual Studio 2015 (C#).

Is it possible to use LinqToSql on a MySql Database ?

Or is it possible to use MySql as Destination Server on Microsoft Integration Service ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export data from SQL Server 2005 to MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129/how-to-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-mysql)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I Solved the problem by editing the .Net Console application in order to implement a loop-insert in MySql Database using **MySql.Data.MySqlClient**.

It is not fast for big data loading but it works properly.

Comment: "It's not fast" is a serious problem when talking about databases. You should check how bulk loading works on MySQL instead. Check [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html). SSIS is also a good option, certainly better than writing your own console program. You could transfer data directly from a SQL Server source to a MySQL destination, *and* perform transformations

Comment: I agree, but SSIS is not present in my environment. The only thing I can use is a console application.

Comment: Are you sure? The `Export Wizard` in SSMS actually generates SSIS packages that can be scheduled for execution.

Comment: Anyway, you *can* export the data to a file that can be used with LOAD DATA statement or mysqlimport.